# 200kb image to base64 cannot send to web service

Tags: android, json, web-services, base64

I got bad request 400 when i send base64 image in the web service,
I put base64 string to JSON and POST it using retrofit. here is my code

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("IMAGE PATH");
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
            String imgbase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP + Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

And add to JSONObject

```
  JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jo.put("id",users.get(counter).getId());
                jo.put("firstname",users.get(counter).getFirstname());
                jo.put("middlename",users.get(counter).getMiddlename());
                jo.put("lastname",users.get(counter).getLastname());
                jo.put("suffix",users.get(counter).getSuffix());
                jo.put("image",imgbase64);
          jo.put("date_registered",users.get(counter).getDate_registered());


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And I will send it using retrofit

```
 ServiceInterface si = RestClient.getClient();
 Observable<Response> call = si.postUser(jo.toString());
```

Image size is 200kb and i got an error bad request
but when my image size is only 10kb it works fine.
please help.

Comment: base64 string for large size images can be really long. That's why sometimes they are just more than the size that can be sent to an api. Better would be to use multipart to upload files

Comment: how can webservice receive the multipart parameter? my webservice accepts only JSON ?

Comment: you have to modify your webservice too

Comment: do you have any sample for web service? I dont have any idea:( please help

Comment: see this tutorial http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Below solution for decode the image and send

```
   Bitmap bitmap;
   String encodedString ="";
   String filepath=""; // your uploaded image file path

   try {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            // Encode Image to String
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

You can put **encodedString**  to the your JSON.

Here is the PHP webservice for decode and upload image to server, also perform your operation to database.

```
 <?php

   include('../db/config.php');  

    // Get image string posted from Android App
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    // Get file name posted from Android App
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];// this your image filename like testimage.jpg

    //other files
    $id= $_REQUEST['id'];
    $firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $middlename = $_REQUEST['middlename'];// add your parameter

    // Decode Image
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    // Images will be saved under 'www/imgupload/uplodedimages' folder
    $file = fopen('uploads/'.$filename, 'wb');
    // Create File
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    // echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
    if(isset($filename) && $filename !=''){
        $fileUrl = "http://yourdomain/android/upload/".$filename;
      }else{
        $fileUrl = '';
      }
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_name(Id,firstName,middleName,FileUrl) VALUES ('$Id','$firstName','$middleName','$fileUrl')");

  ?>
```

I suggest to try to use this solution, It will work.

Comment: still I got HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST

Comment: check your web service URL and modify your web service .Paste the code snippiest of web service.

Comment: my webservice parameter is JSON,

Comment: ex. {"name":"asd","image":"base64string"}

Comment: Check added web service code and check your web service as well

Comment: your added webservice accepts JSON object ? I already have that , and it works in small size of image, but when my image is 100kb up , it return bad request:(

Comment: It will work upto 1MB image. Its work for me. Please check your code

Comment: im using liferay v.6.2 webservice builder. and here is the exact error in my tomcat. org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.