# how upload image with text to server without affecting image quality,

Tags: android

i upload image to server with help of volley and bitmap and i successfully pass the data, but when i take the image using camera the image quality become so poor and also when i pass an image of size above 500kb the app become crash. Why this happen??
can anyone help me,

this is how my camera intent perform

```
 private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        //fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (thumbnail!=null){
        addImageNew.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }


}
```

this is how my gallery intent perform

```
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    thumbnail=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            thumbnail =    MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (thumbnail!=null){
        addImageNew.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
}
```

this how i convert Bitmap to string

```
 public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

NOTE: i have only problem in image quality and high size image passing

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use below link solution. It may be work for you.

[200kb image to base64 cannot send to web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459388/200kb-image-to-base64-cannot-send-to-web-service/40459959#40459959)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find where `getStringImage(Bitmap bmp)` is called, but you can try to do something like that:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
getStringImage(bitmap);
```

Or maybe you can change the `compress` to 100, for high quality:

```
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
```

Comment: i use getStringImage() to covert bitmap to String of pass to server

String image = getStringImage(thumbnail);
/** other code**/
 params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image); //for pass image to server